# Login redirects to wrong page

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I have just started using jQuery mobile and have spent time reading the docs. However, I am having a problem after a user logs in. After a successfull login, the user is taken to his/her page which there is a simple listview. If a user clicks on any item, then they are taken back to the login page. The page seems to be loading ok and I am sure that my markup is correct because in the chrome address bar, the address that i click shows as:

`http://localhost/sample/app/test.php#ctlpnl`,

which is the correct address for that link. Can someone show me my error. Thanks

LOGIN HTML

```
<div data-role="page" id="login" data-title="Test Login" data-theme="b">
    <div data-role="header">
      <h1>Sample Login</h1>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content">

    <form method="post" id="login" rel="external" action="<?php echo KT_escapeAttribute(KT_getFullUri()); ?>">

    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
     <label for="kt_login_user">Email *</label>
     <input type="text" name="kt_login_user" id="kt_login_user" value="<?php echo KT_escapeAttribute($row_rscustom['kt_login_user']); ?>" size="66" placeholder="janedoe@example.com" />

    <div id="userError">
     <?php echo $tNGs->displayFieldHint("kt_login_user");?>
     <?php echo $tNGs->displayFieldError("custom", "kt_login_user"); ?>
    </div>
  </div>

   <div data-role="fieldcontain">
     <label for="kt_login_password">Password *</label>
     <label for="kt_login_rememberme"></label>
     <input type="password" name="kt_login_password" id="kt_login_password" value="" size="46" placeholder="******" />

    <div id="passError">
     <?php echo $tNGs->displayFieldHint("kt_login_password");?>
     <?php echo $tNGs->displayFieldError("custom", "kt_login_password"); ?>
     <?php echo $tNGs->displayFieldError("custom", "kt_login_rememberme"); ?>
    </div>

   </div>

   <div id="login_message"></div>

   <div id="submitDiv" data-role="fieldcontain">
    <input name="kt_login1" id="kt_login1" type="submit" value="Login" data-inline="true" />
   </div>

   </form>

  </div>

    <div data-role="footer"">
      <h4>test 2009-2011</h4>
    </div>
</div>
```

USERS INDEX.PHP

```
<div data-role="page" id="page">
    <div data-role="header">
      <h1>Users Page One</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <ul data-role="listview">
         <li><a href="#requests">Requests</a></li>
         <li><a href="#ctlpnl">Control Panel</a></li>
         <li><a href="#userhelp">Help</a></li>
         <li><a href="users/logout.php" rel="external">Logout</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer">
      <h4>Users Start Page</h4>
    </div>
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="ctlpnl" data-theme="b">
    <div data-role="header">
      <h1>Control Panel</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
      <?php echo $_SESSION['kt_name_usr']; ?> Control Panel
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer">
      <h4>Control Panel Footer</h4>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: cam someone explain why no one has commented good or bad on this question? thanks

Comment: You don't say what's going wrong. You just tell what should happen and then there's a bunch of code. What is the problem? Is it in the Javascript or PHP? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @frog at the simplest level, there is a login page, admin page and user page. Fistly, the user is presented with the login screen. That authenticates and denies successfully. Once authenticated, they are then directed to either the user page or the admin. What is happening, is once authenticated, I expect to see http://localhost/sample/app/users/index.php in the address bar but instead it shows http://localhost/sample/app/test.php#/sample/app/test.php which is the login area http://localhost/logistor/app/test.php. The thing is that the page I am presented with, is the correct page. Thanks

Comment: So you mean the user is not redirected to the correct page? Are you doing an actual redirect or is jQuery Mobile handling it? You say that _"the page I am presented with, is the correct page."_. That what's the problem?

Comment: @frog I am using $.mobile.changePage( "users/index.php/", { transition: "slideup"} ); to select the page. It's when i click a link in that page that it is redirecting back to test.php for the login. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have probably forgotten to start session (BEFORE any output, add this code)

```
session_start();
```

Comment: genesis the sessions are handled by the php classes. they are working correctly and if i do this <?php echo $_SESSION['kt_name_usr']; ?> it outputs correctly. I only pasted the code that was relevant to my problem. The code I am using is working in the static site, just cannot seem to get it to work with mobile

Answer (score 1):

I can't see any mention of [session_start()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) in your PHP.  Looks like the browser isn't being sent a cookie.